# Conditional Join for on range

Tags: python, pandas, join

I'm trying to join df 1 and 2 on the basis if the df 1's entry_time column have a values in range of +30 or -30 from the entry_time values in df2

CurrentlyI'm using this code my memory runs out:

```
original_entry_time = df1.entry_time.head()
entry_time = df2.entry_time.values

i, j = np.where((original_entry_time[:, None] >= entry_time-30) & (entry_time[:, None] <= entry_time+30))

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df1.values[i], df2.values[j]]),
    columns=dataset.columns.append(entry_time.columns)
)
```

```
Dataframe 1
|index|entry_time|
   1       60        
   2.      100
   3.      120
   4.      170
   5.      180
   6.      220
```

Dataframe2:

```
|index|entry_time|Price|

|1       60       120|
|2       120       70|
|3       180       60|
|4       240       80|
|5       300       20|
|6       360       35|
```

Final Dataframe

```
|index|entry_time|Price|

|1       60       120|
|2       100       70|
|3       120       70|
|4       170       60|
|5       180       60|
|6       220       80|
```

Comment: Why does `3 | 120 | 70` not appear in the results? (`|3|120|` exists in the first dataframe, `|2|120|70|` exists in the second and 120 is ±30 of 120)

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `merge_asof`

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2, on = 'entry_time',direction = 'nearest',tolerance = 30)
   index_x  entry_time  index_y  Price
0        1          60        1    120
1        2         100        2     70
2        3         120        2     70
3        4         170        3     60
4        5         180        3     60
5        6         220        4     80
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Most other solutions are required a lot of memory. This one is slow but avoid ram issues.

```
for index,row in tqdm(df2.iterrows()):

  df1.loc[(df1["entry_time"]>= row["entry_time"] -30) & (df1["entry_time"] < row["entry_time"]+30),"price"] = row["price"]
```